# What protocol should be adopted by a Type for a generic function to take any number type as an argument in Swift?

Tags: swift, numbers, int, double

I want to make a function accept any number (Int, Float, Double, ...) in Swift

```
func myFunction <T : "What to put here"> (number : T) ->  {
    //...
}
```

without using NSNumber

Answer (score 54, accepted):

*Update:* The answer below still applies in principle, but Swift 4 completed a redesign of the numeric protocols, such that adding your own is often unnecessary. Take a look at the [standard library's numeric protocols](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numbers_and_basic_values/numeric_protocols) before you build your own system.

---

This actually isn't possible out of the box in Swift. To do this you'll need to create a new protocol, declared with whatever methods and operators you're going to use inside your generic function. This process will work for you, but the exact details will depend a little on what your generic function does. Here's how you'd do it for a function that gets a number `n` and returns `(n - 1)^2`.

First, define your protocol, with the operators and an initializer that takes an `Int` (that's so we can subtract one).

```
protocol NumericType {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func -(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func /(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func %(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    init(_ v: Int)
}
```

All of the numeric types *already implement these*, but at this point the compiler doesn't know that they conform to the new `NumericType` protocol. You have to make this explicit -- Apple calls this "declaring protocol adoption with an extension." We'll do this for `Double`, `Float`, and all the integer types:

```
extension Double : NumericType { }
extension Float  : NumericType { }
extension Int    : NumericType { }
extension Int8   : NumericType { }
extension Int16  : NumericType { }
extension Int32  : NumericType { }
extension Int64  : NumericType { }
extension UInt   : NumericType { }
extension UInt8  : NumericType { }
extension UInt16 : NumericType { }
extension UInt32 : NumericType { }
extension UInt64 : NumericType { }
```

Now we can write our actual function, using the `NumericType` protocol as a generic constraint.

```
func minusOneSquared<T : NumericType> (number : T) -> T {
    let minusOne = number - T(1)
    return minusOne * minusOne
}

minusOneSquared(5)              // 16
minusOneSquared(2.3)            // 1.69
minusOneSquared(2 as UInt64)    // 1
```

Comment: Yay, this is way nicer than having to implement all your own operators like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/28457725/466698 Why isn’t a protocol like this included in Swift itself?

Comment: Some caution. NumericType, as implemented here, as Self requirements. So you wouldn't be able to do something like var values = [NumericType]. If you want to do that, you have to supply your own operators, alas.

Comment: With this method is there a way to convert `T` to an `Int`? Like `Int(number)`? Or use other functions on it like `floor(number)`?

Comment: In Swift 4 the Numeric protocol is there which defines all but the '/' and '%' operator. This protocol is implemented by both floating point and integer types.