# Swift number generics?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have this function that is going to calculate the hypotenuse from 2 numbers

```
func hypotenusa<T>(nr1: T, nr2: T) -> T {
    return sqrt( pow(nr1, 2) + pow(nr2, 2) )
}

// v Simpler situation v

func addition<T>(nr1: T, nr2: T) -> T {
    return nr1 + nr2
}
```

I want to use generics so I don't have to make 3 copies of this which uses Int, Float, Double separately

But this isn't working, I think generics is really difficult to work with, please help me :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swift generics aren't like C++ templates.

In C++, you can just try to use a parameterized type however you want, and it's not an error until the compiler tries to instantiate the template with some type that doesn't support what your template tries to do.

In Swift, the generic construct can only use a parameterized type in ways known to be valid when the generic construct is first parsed. You specify these "ways known to be valid" by constraining the parameterized type with protocols.

You cannot call `sqrt` or `pow` with generic-typed arguments, because those functions are not themselves generic.  They have each two definitions:

```
func pow(_: Double, _: Double) -> Double
func pow(lhs: Float, rhs: Float) -> Float
func sqrt(x: Double) -> Double
func sqrt(x: Float) -> Float
```

You could write type-specific versions of `hypotenusa`:

```
func hypotenusa(a: Float, b: Float) -> Float
func hypotenusa(a: Double, b: Double) -> Double
func hypotenusa(a: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
```

I'm not sure why you'd create an `Int` version at all, since very few right triangles have integer hypotenuses.

Anyway, you don't need to define the `Float` and `Double` versions at all, because the standard library already provides a `hypot` function defined on `Float` and `Double`:

```
func hypot(_: Double, _: Double) -> Double
func hypot(lhs: Float, rhs: Float) -> Float
```

You could create another override for `CGFloat`:

```
func hypot(l: CGFloat, r: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return hypot(Double(l), Double(r))
}
```

As for your `addition` function, it has the same problem as your `hypotenusa` function: the `+` operator is not defined entirely generically.  It has some generic definitions (unlike `sqrt` and `pow`), but those only cover the integer types (see `IntegerArithmeticType`). There's not generic definition of `+` that covers the floating-point types. Swift defines all of these versions of `+` with explicit types:

```
func +(lhs: Float, rhs: Float) -> Float
func +<T>(lhs: Int, rhs: UnsafePointer<T>) -> UnsafePointer<T>
func +<T>(lhs: UnsafePointer<T>, rhs: Int) -> UnsafePointer<T>
func +(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int
func +(lhs: UInt, rhs: UInt) -> UInt
func +(lhs: Int64, rhs: Int64) -> Int64
func +(lhs: UInt64, rhs: UInt64) -> UInt64
func +<T>(lhs: Int, rhs: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<T>
func +<T>(lhs: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>, rhs: Int) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<T>
func +(lhs: Int32, rhs: Int32) -> Int32
func +(lhs: UInt32, rhs: UInt32) -> UInt32
func +(lhs: Int16, rhs: Int16) -> Int16
func +(lhs: UInt16, rhs: UInt16) -> UInt16
func +(lhs: Int8, rhs: Int8) -> Int8
func +(lhs: UInt8, rhs: UInt8) -> UInt8
func +(lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Double
func +(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> String
func +(lhs: Float80, rhs: Float80) -> Float80
```

Comment: I see. I didnt know of hypot() haha i feel so silly =S so maybe generics isnt as advanced as I thought :(

Comment: Float80 is not defined for sqrt or pow, you'd need to write you own or use a lib like boost

Answer (score 6):

With Swift 5, according to your needs, you can pick one of the following ways in order to solve your problem.

---

### #1. Using `FloatingPoint` protocol as a parameter generic constraint

The [Apple Developer Documentation for `FloatingPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint) shows the following `hypotenuse` function implementation as an example of `FloatingPoint` usage:

```
func hypotenuse<T: FloatingPoint>(_ a: T, _ b: T) -> T {
    return (a * a + b * b).squareRoot()
}

let (dx, dy) = (3.0, 4.0)
let result = hypotenuse(dx, dy)
print(result) // prints: 5.0
```

---

### #2. Using `AdditiveArithmetic` protocol as a parameter generic constraint

[`AdditiveArithmetic`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/additivearithmetic) has the following declaration:

> A type with values that support addition and subtraction.

The Playground sample code below shows a possible usage of `AdditiveArithmetic` as a function parameter generic constraint:

```
func addition<T: AdditiveArithmetic>(a: T, b: T) -> T {
    return a + b
}

let result = addition(a: 3, b: 4)
print(result) // prints: 7
```

---

### #3. Using `Numeric` protocol as a parameter generic constraint

[`Numeric`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric) has the following declaration:

> A type with values that support multiplication.

The Playground sample code below shows a possible usage of `Numeric` as a function parameter generic constraint:

```
func multiply<T: Numeric>(a: T, b: T, c: T) -> T {
    return a * b * c
}

let result = multiply(a: 3, b: 4, c: 5)
print(result) // prints: 60
```

Note that `Numeric` protocol inherit from `AdditiveArithmetic` protocol.

---

The Apple Developer Documentation contains a dedicated page for all numeric protocols: [Numeric Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/numbers_and_basic_values/numeric_protocols).

Comment: Note that the already available `hypot` function is usable with `CGFloat` for quite some time already.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575513/what-protocol-should-be-adopted-by-a-type-for-a-generic-function-to-take-any-num) is what you need:

You need to explicitly create a new protocol and extend the types you want (Int, Float, Double) to conform to the protocol. Than in your generic declaration you do 
`func addition<T: protocolJustCreated>(nr1: T, nr2: T) -> T {}`

Read the answer I linked for a more complete answer. No need to repeat here.

Answer (score 0):

Sqrt() and pow() both specify their parameters as either double or float. In order to meet your goal of using this one function for Int, Float, and Double you will need to also make generics of sqrt() and pow() functions.

Comment: If you reload the question Ive added a simpler situation. In that addition() on the return line I get an error "Cannot invoke + with an argument of typ (T, T)"