# Usage of arithmetic operants (+, -, /, *) with generic types

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem with a class using a generic type T for an internal array which can be an `Int` or `Double`. The function `average` shall calcucualte the average values of all `Int` or `Double` values in the array.

```
class MathStatistics<T: Comparable> {
    var numbers = [T]()

    func average() -> Double? {
        if numbers.count == 0 {
            return nil
        }

        var sum:T

        for value in numbers {
           sum = sum + value
        }

        return (sum / numbers.count)
    }
}
```

Xcode reports an error in line the following lines:

`sum = sum + value`
Binary operator '+' cannot apply two T operants

`return (sum / numbers.count)`
Couldn't find an overload for '/' that accepts the supplied arguments

Comment: Why are you using Comparable? Why not just cast the integer to a double?

Comment: This should answer a major part of your question: [What protocol should be adopted by a Type for a generic function to take any number type as an argument in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575513/what-protocol-should-be-adopted-by-a-type-for-a-generic-function-to-take-any-num). You'll have to extend the protocol if you want all possible types to be convertible to a Double.

Comment: `Comparable` I need for other functions which I excluded here to simplify the example.

Comment: @Morpheus78: The *result* should always be a Double, no matter what the element type is?

Comment: I was thinking about the following situation with an Int array of [3, 5, 2]. The average values is 3.333. If I use T it will be just 3. Maybe it will be better to implement to functions. One with T and one with Double or Float as return value.

Comment: @Morpheus78: You can define a protocol and a method which converts all the numbers to Double and computes the average as a Double (that's why I asked).

Comment: @Martin R: Maybe that's the better way, because now I have the problem to convert the generic type `T` to `Double`. Up to know I found no solution for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you need to create a new `protocol` that lets Swift know any instance of `T` can have numeric operators performed on it, for example:

```
protocol NumericType: Equatable, Comparable {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func -(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func /(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func %(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    init(_ v: Int)
}

extension Double  : NumericType {}
extension Int     : NumericType {}
```

Source: [What protocol should be adopted by a Type for a generic function to take any number type as an argument in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575513/what-protocol-should-be-adopted-by-a-type-for-a-generic-function-to-take-any-num)

Now when you define your `MathStatistics` class:

```
class MathStatistics<T: NumericType> {
    var numbers = [T]()

    func average() -> T? {
        if numbers.count == 0 {
            return nil
        }

        let sum = numbers.reduce(T(0)) { $0 + $1 }
        return sum / T(numbers.count)
    }
}
```

Now you can use `MathsStatistics` like so:

```
let stats = MathStatistics<Int>()
stats.numbers = [1, 3, 5]
println(stats.average()) // Prints: Optional(3)
```

Comment: Perfect, that does exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to compute the average in floating point arithmetic
then you have to define a protocol which describes
all types which can be converted to `Double`:

```
protocol DoubleConvertible {
    var doubleValue : Double { get }
}

extension Double : DoubleConvertible {
    var doubleValue : Double { return self }
}

extension Int : DoubleConvertible {
    var doubleValue : Double { return Double(self) }
}
```

Then your class would be:

```
class MathStatistics<T: DoubleConvertible> {
    var numbers = [T]()

    func average() -> Double? {
        if numbers.count == 0 {
            return nil
        }

        var sum = 0.0
        for value in numbers {
            sum = sum + value.doubleValue
        }
        return (sum / numbers.count.doubleValue)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let stats = MathStatistics<Int>()
stats.numbers = [3, 5,2]
println(stats.average()) // Optional(3.33333333333333)
```

Comment: Seems not to work for me. I always receive the  error message `T does not have a member named doubleValue` in line `sum = sum + value.doubleValue`. If I understood it correctly `<T: DoubleConvertible>` just says that `T` supports this protocol. Do I have to implement in `MathStatistics` the `var doubleValue...`?

Comment: @Morpheus78: Strange. I have tested that code before posting it and it compiled and worked as expected.

Comment: @Morpheus78: ... Did you add the extension methods for Double and Int?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in Swift. See answer below.

Comment: @Morpheus78: I don't think that is a bug in Swift. The problem is that you way of "merging" the two answers does not work. See ABakerSmith' comment below.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a bug in SWIFT when I want to use two protocols on a generic type T.

The following code works perfectly.

```
protocol DoubleConvertible {
    var doubleValue : Double { get }
}

protocol NumericType: Equatable, Comparable, DoubleConvertible {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func -(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func /(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func %(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    init(_ v: Int)
    init(_ v: Double)
}

extension Double : NumericType {
    var doubleValue : Double { return self }
}

extension Int    : NumericType {
    var doubleValue : Double { return Double(self) }
}

class MathStatistics<T: NumericType> {
    var numbers = [T]()

    func average() -> Double? {
        if numbers.count == 0 {
            return nil
        }

        let sum = numbers.reduce(T(0)) { $0 + $1 }
        return sum.doubleValue / numbers.count.doubleValue
    }
}
```

This version produces the error `T does not have a member named doubleValue`in line `return sum.doubleValue / numbers.count.doubleValue`

```
protocol NumericType: Equatable, Comparable {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func -(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func /(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func %(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    init(_ v: Int)
    init(_ v: Double)
}

protocol DoubleConvertible {
    var doubleValue : Double { get }
}

extension Double : DoubleConvertible {
    var doubleValue : Double { return self }
}

extension Int    : DoubleConvertible {
    var doubleValue : Double { return Double(self) }
}

class MathStatistics<T: NumericType, DoubleConvertible > {
    var numbers = [T]()

    func average() -> Double? {
        if numbers.count == 0 {
            return nil
        }

        let sum = numbers.reduce(T(0)) { $0 + $1 }
        return sum.doubleValue / numbers.count.doubleValue  // error T does not have a member named doubleValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `T: NumericType, DoubleConvertible` with `T: protocol<NumericType, DoubleConvertible>` or `T where T: NumericType, T: DoubleConvertible`.