# Swift implicit protocol

Tags: swift, generics

Is there any way to describe in Swift an `IntegerType` that has a `max` property? (something similar to implicit interfaces in go)

There is no protocol to describe a `max` attribute, and even if I create one, `IntegerType` does not explicitly implement it.

So basically I'm looking for something like:

```
class Test<T: IntegerType where ?> { // <- ? = something like 'has a "max: Self"' property
}

let t = Test<UInt8>()
```

or maybe something like:

```
implicit protocol IntegerTypeWithMax: IntegerType {
    static var max: Self { get }
}

class Test<T: IntegerTypeWithMax> {
}

let t = Test<UInt8>()
```

Comment: Just remove the "implicit" and then it compiles ...

Comment: @MartinR, it compiles, but it doesn't do what I would like it to do, since `IntegerType` does not implement `IntegerTypeWithMax`, so I can't instantiate a class with any `IntegerType` (such as `UInt8`) as parameter.

Comment: The compiler does not know if all types conforming to `IntegerType` have a `max` property. You have to tell him with e.g. `extension UInt8 : IntegerTypeWithMax { }`. (There may be a better way with the new protocol extensions in Swift 2.)

Comment: @MartinR, exactly, that's what I was wondering - is there any way to describe an `IntegerType` with a `max` property, as opposed to just any `IntegerType`, like you can do in go (which has the notion of implicit interface), or TypeScript for example?

Comment: I have no experience with go, so I cannot compare, but I think I understand now what you mean. In Swift you *can* defined a IntegerTypeWithMax protocol, but the compiler does not automatically infer that `UInt8` conforms to that protocol just because it has a `max` method. You have to tell him.

Comment: @MartinR, so in Swift what you would do would be to declare a `IntegerTypeWithMax` protocol, then extend all the `IntegerType`s you're interested in to implement the protocol?

Comment: Yes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575513/what-protocol-should-be-adopted-by-a-type-for-a-generic-function-to-take-any-num for an example.

Comment: @MartinR, great, sounds good. Can you please add this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swift compiler does not automatically infer protocol conformance
even if a type implements all the required properties/methods. So if you define

```
protocol IntegerTypeWithMax: IntegerType {
    static var max: Self { get }
}
```

you still have to make the integer types that you are interested in
conform to that protocol:

```
extension UInt8 : IntegerTypeWithMax { }
extension UInt16 : IntegerTypeWithMax { }
// ...
```

The extension block is empty because `UInt8`, `UInt16` already have
a static `max` method.

Then

```
class Test<T: IntegerTypeWithMax> {
}

let t = Test<UInt8>()
```

compiles and works as expected.