# Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands

Tags: swift

I am using Generics to add different types like Int, Double, Float, etc. I used the code below but I'm getting error "Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands".

```
func add<T>(num1: T,num2: T) -> T {
    return num1 + num2
}
```

Comment: And the question is ... ?

Comment: What if the type <T> is not a number? What wild happen?

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575513/what-protocol-should-be-adopted-by-a-type-for-a-generic-function-to-take-any-num

Comment: @A-Live Obviously, the question is _“Why am I getting that error? / How do I fix my code so that I don't get that error?”_  Toxic sass like yours does not help SO.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Swift doesn't know that the generic type T has a '+' operator. You can't use + on any type: e.g. on two view controllers + doesn't make too much sense

You can use protocol conformance to let swift know some things about your type!

I had a go in a playground and this is probably what you are looking for :)

```
protocol Addable {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

func add<T: Addable>(num1: T, _ num2: T) -> T {
    return num1 + num2
}

extension Int: Addable {}
extension Double: Addable {}
extension Float: Addable {}

add(3, 0.2)
```

Let me know if you need any of the concepts demonstrated here explained

Comment: try add(CGFloat(2.5), Float(2.0))

Comment: @LeoDabus Swift doesn't have a definition of + for CGFloat and Float. To solve this you can define + for CGFloat and Float.  Alternatively you could change the solution slightly to cast to say, the first type.

Comment: I believe in Swift 3 the protocol must use the static keyword, e.g. :
protocol Addable {
    static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

Comment: It's quite counter intuitive, that 1. You have to extend the type you want it to work with. 2. Your generic has to actually conform and it's not kept as a true generic...which leads to an interesting conclusion: If you ever do any sort of computation on your generics (specifying something and therefore limiting it to be able to cope with that specification), then you need to define a protocol for it, or use some protocol...

Answer (score 23):

In Swift 4 / Xcode 9+ you can take advantage of the [Numeric protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric).

```
func add<T: Numeric>(num1: T, num2: T) -> T {
    return num1 + num2
}

print(add(num1: 3.7, num2: 44.9)) // 48.6
print(add(num1: 27, num2: 100))  // 127
```

Using this means you won't have to create a special protocol yourself.

This will only work in the cases where you need the functionality provided by the Numeric protocol. You may need to do something similar to @adam's answer for % and other operators, or you can leverage other protocols provided by Apple in the Xcode 9 SDK.

Comment: But with this solution all types must be same... the types must be able to be different i.e. Int + Float

Answer (score 6):

For those who wish to use comparison such as `<` , `>` etc, simply tell Swift that your generic type adopt to comperable protocol like so: -

`func genericComparison<T: Comparable>(left: LinkedList<T>, right: LinkedList<T>) -> LinkedList<T>`

Comment: In fact if you put `Comparable` at class level it solves the purpose too.Like this: 
`final class BSTree<Type: Comparable>` without the left right.

Answer (score 1):

To add `num1` and `num2`, first you need to make sure that it is of type `Numeric`. So, the code should look like this:

```
func add<T : Numeric>(num1: T,num2: T) -> T {
    return num1 + num2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol Addable {
    static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

func add<T: Addable>(num1: T, _ num2: T) -> T {
    return num1 + num2
}

extension Int: Addable {}
extension Double: Addable {}
extension Float: Addable {}
```

Usage :-

```
add(num1: 3, 5)
```

This Code changes of above answer i have added `static` keyword otherwise code will not run for latest Swift version