# Swift 2.0 Binary operator "-" cannot be applied to two T operands

Tags: ios, swift, generics

There is my code:

```
func singleInterpolation(value1: T, value2: T) -> T {
    return value1 + (value2 - value1) / 2
}
```

I've got the error: *Binary operator "-" cannot be applied to two T operands*

Which protocol I need to use for fix that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125637/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-two-t-operands

Comment: Sorry, but it's not good example. It shouldn't  be custom protocol

Comment: You're receiving a similar error. Search on SO for the error you're receiving there are dozens of similar questions. The question I posted has a good answer to reference.

Comment: @IlyaKharabet you have exactly the same problem as in the referenced question, and the solution  and the comments over there should answer your question.

Comment: What is `T` and where is it defined? What result do you expect if `T` is – for example – `String`?