# Abstract Access to Bitwise Shifts in Swift

Tags: swift, polymorphism, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

So a little while ago I was working on some code in Swift that would allow me to do some useful extra manipulation of integers as binary, including getting the highest and lowest bits that are actually set.

As an example, here's a basic property I added that is now broken:

```
extension IntegerType {
    var hiBit:Self { return ~self.allZeroes << ((sizeof(Self) * 8) - 1) }
}
```

This won't compile now because `IntegerType` no longer conforms to `BitwiseOperationsType` so the tilde operator and `allZeroes` properties are no longer available to it. Likewise there doesn't appear to be any requirement anymore for structs implementing `IntegerType` or `BitwiseOperationsType` to have shift operators, they just seem to be defined by convention now, unless I've missed something. This means that I can't transplant my code to `BitwiseOperationsType` either, even though it seems like the more logical place for it to be.

So my question is; where do I implement my code at the highest level? I don't want to have to duplicate it for every specific integer type, which is why I was extending `IntegerType` to begin with.

Also as an aside, I originally implemented `hiBit` as a `static` property, but these no longer appear to be supported, which is weird as they clearly were, and the error message implies that they will be in future, suggesting they were pulled from the spec; but I'm not running the Xcode beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no protocol which defines the bit shift operators, so you have
to define your own:

```
protocol ShiftOperationsType : BitwiseOperationsType {
    func <<(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func >>(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    init(_ value : Int)
}
```

Unfortunately, you have to declare the conformance of the integer type
to that protocol explicitly for each type (at present there is no
simpler solution, compare [What protocol should be adopted by a Type for a generic function to take any number type as an argument in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575513/what-protocol-should-be-adopted-by-a-type-for-a-generic-function-to-take-any-num)).

```
extension Int : ShiftOperationsType {}
extension Int8 : ShiftOperationsType {}
extension Int16 : ShiftOperationsType {}
extension Int32: ShiftOperationsType {}
extension Int64: ShiftOperationsType {}
extension UInt : ShiftOperationsType {}
extension UInt8 : ShiftOperationsType {}
extension UInt16 : ShiftOperationsType {}
extension UInt32 : ShiftOperationsType {}
extension UInt64 : ShiftOperationsType {}
```

But then you can define `hiBit` as a generic static property:

```
extension ShiftOperationsType {
    static var hiBit : Self {
        return (~allZeros) << Self(sizeof(Self) * 8 - 1)
    }
}
```

The `init` method in the protocol is necessary because `sizeof()`
returns an `Int` and has to be converted to `Self`.

Comment: Thanks, this has got me up and running again! Seems like something that should really be under BitwiseOperationsType or something, oh well, maybe one day Apple will stop messing around with the number protocols and we can actually start using them ;)