# Literals in Swift generics

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift2

I'm trying to implement a generic sign function in Swift so that it can be used with any floating-point type:

```
func sign<T> (value:T) -> T {
    if value < 0.0 {
        return -1.0
    }
    if value > 0.0 {
        return 1.0
    }
    return 0.0
}
```

But this error stands in the way:

> Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and
>   'Double'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a type constraint (`MyFloats` below) to which your floating point types *conform*. You let this type constraint itself conform to `Comparable`, so that you may make use of the less than binary infix operator `<` when comparing the values of your generics. Also, for your example given above, the `MyFloats` type constraint need contain only a single blueprint; an initializer for a `Double` argument. This initalizer already exists for `Double`, `Float` and `CGFloat` types, but since a protocol cannot know which types that conforms *to it*, you need to include this blueprint.

```
protocol MyFloats : Comparable {
    init(_ value: Double)
}

extension Double : MyFloats { }
extension Float : MyFloats { }
extension CGFloat : MyFloats { }

func sign<T: MyFloats> (value:T) -> T {
    if value < T(0.0) {
        return T(-1.0)
    }
    if value > T(0.0) {
        return T(1.0)
    }
    return T(0.0)
}
```

Comment: @DesmondHume Happy to help. Note that since your `sign` function only contains "double literals" that are can in fact be represented as integer literals (`1.0` as `1`, `0.0` as `0` etc), I believe Nate Cooks solution below would be preferable for you, as you needn't create a custom protocol and extend types to this. Note however that the `SignedNumberType` solution will allow for all types that conform to this protocol (not just floating point types) to call your function `sign`.

Comment: ... If you make use of Nates solution but only only want it available for floats (`Double`, `Float` and `CGFloat`), you could modify the type constraint in his solution below with the addition of conformance to protocol `FloatingPointType`: `func sign<T: protocol<SignedNumberType, FloatingPointType>> ( ...`

Comment: Your answer's interworkings told me more about Swift than others did and this solution is more flexible to be applied to other purposes.

Comment: Ok! I'll leave these comments here for thread visitors that possibly want less type constraint customization (-> Nates answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you constrain `T` to `SignedNumberType`, you'll be able to do everything you want. It inherits from `Comparable` and can convert from integer literals, the two things you need there.

```
func sign<T: SignedNumberType> (value:T) -> T {
    if value < 0 {
        return -1
    }
    if value > 0 {
        return 1
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: `SignedNumberType` does not include an initializer for `Double` arguments,  so using this method alone; the `value < 0.0` comparison will be difficult to make generic.

Comment: If you compare with 0 instead of 0.0 it'll work properly. Likewise the return values.

Comment: Ah you are right, he only uses integer literals (as doubles) in his example above, my bad!

Comment: My question was about floating-point literals in Swift generics. This answer is just good for implementing a sign function.

Comment: @DesmondHume ?? sign as is defined by Nate, works with Double and Float as well! returning type will be the same as type of parameter of the function. If you are looking for something else, do it ... and ask again.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575513/what-protocol-should-be-adopted-by-a-type-for-a-generic-function-to-take-any-num) answer. For your use case you need to create a new `protocol` that extends `Comparable` and extend the `Float` and`Double` Swift types by using an `extension`.

Finally you'll be able to use this protocol as condition of the generic parameter.

```
func sign<T : MyCustomNumberProtocol> (value:T) -> T
```

Comment: This will not solve the above as the protocol `NumericType` (in linked thread) does not explicitly conform to `Comparable`, hence existence of `<` operator cannot be inferred from the `MyCustomNumberProtocol` alone.

Comment: @dfri thank's, that's true! I've forgotten this step in my description. Now I've updated my answer by this fact.