# Compare three values for equality

Tags: swift, if-statement, compare

Does anybody know of a shortcut to test whether three numbers are the same? I know this works:

```
if number1 == number2 && number2 == number3 {

}
```

But I would like something cleaner, such as;

```
if number1 == number2 == number3 {

}
```

It's quite important as I'm comparing a lot of different values.

Comment: I'm afraid it could be asked already, though I can't find a dupe.

Comment: Please note that less code does not necessarily mean faster execution. Finally if you need to perform many operations and you need real speed you should consider the [simd](http://www.russbishop.net/swift-2-simd) instructions available in Swift.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the power of tuples and the Transitive Property of Equality.

```
if (number1, number2) == (number2, number3) {

}
```

The clause of this IF is true only when `number1` is equals to `number2` **AND** `number2` is equals to `number3`. It means that the 3 values must be equals.

Comment: Similarly, I did `(number1 == number2) && (number2 == number3)`

Comment: At this point, someone might just as well type `number1 == number2 && number2 == number3`.

Answer (score 16):

You could use a set

```
if Set([number1, number2, number3]).count == 1 {
    ...
```

though I'd argue it isn't as transparent as multiple if clauses

Comment: The post mentions "I'm comparing a lot of different values", so this is the more sustainable approach than using tuples.

Answer (score 7):

You can add them in an array and use sets:

```
var someSet = NSSet(array: [2,2,2])

if someSet.count == 1 {
    print("Same values")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't know of anything other than a Set, I'd suggest wrapping it in a function to make your intent clear. Something along these lines:

```
func allItemsEqual<T>(items:[T]) -> Bool {
    guard items.count > 1 else { fatalError("Must have at least two objects to check for equality") }
    return Set(items).count == 1
}

func allItemsEqual(items:T...) -> Bool {
    return equal(items)
}

if allItemsEqual(2,3,2) {
    // false
}

if allItemsEqual(2, 2, 2) {
    // true
}
```

Beyond that, maybe you could get fancy with operator overloading?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
func areEqual<T: NumericType>(numbers: T...) -> Bool {
   let num = numbers[0]
   for number in numbers {
       if number != num {
          return false
       }
   }
   return true
}
```

Where `NumericType` is defined in this post: [What protocol should be adopted by a Type for a generic function to take any number type as an argument in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575513/what-protocol-should-be-adopted-by-a-type-for-a-generic-function-to-take-any-num/)

This will allow you to use the function for all number types

You just pass any number of numbers like:

```
//returns true
if areEqual(1, 1, 1) {
   print("equal")
}
```