# Comparing 2 UIColor(s)

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

This must have been asked before, but I cannot find a suitable reference. I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900603/compare-three-values-for-equality), but that compares three numbers with each other.

I am trying to compare 2 UIColor(s) to avoid duplication. Each color is referenced in r, g, b, alpha. I form the colors so I can control number formatting.

What would be the appropriate way to handle this?

Comment: So you want to know if 2 colors are the same?

Comment: Comparing colors is not a trivial task, do you want to compare them by their RGBA value?

Comment: @appzYourLife, @fpg1503 If i remember correctly `UIColor` is `Equatable`

Comment: Yes, but the `Equatable` implementation does not consider colors created differently (different color spaces)

Comment: If you create all color with the same color space you can just use `==` (like  @appzYourLife said)

Comment: @fpg1503, yes, to try to keep this simple, I just want to compare r, g, b, a values

Comment: @appzYourLife - yes exactly two colors the same -- I'm trying to prevent adding multiple "favorite" colors that are identical

Comment: Could you all please expand how to use equality? Do you mean red1 == red2, and green1 == green2, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are creating all color the same way you can just use `==`.

If your colors are in different color spaces and you just want to compare their RGBA value use the following:

```
extension UIColor {
    func equals(_ rhs: UIColor) -> Bool {
        var lhsR: CGFloat = 0
        var lhsG: CGFloat = 0
        var lhsB: CGFloat = 0
        var lhsA: CGFloat = 0
        self.getRed(&lhsR, green: &lhsG, blue: &lhsB, alpha: &lhsA)

        var rhsR: CGFloat = 0
        var rhsG: CGFloat = 0
        var rhsB: CGFloat = 0
        var rhsA: CGFloat = 0
        rhs.getRed(&rhsR, green: &rhsG, blue: &rhsB, alpha: &rhsA)

        return  lhsR == rhsR &&
                lhsG == rhsG &&
                lhsB == rhsB &&
                lhsA == rhsA
    }
}
```

For instance:

```
let white1 = UIColor.white
let white2 = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
white1 == white2 //false
white1.cgColor == white2.cgColor //false
white1.equals(white2) //true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize as UIColor, you should be able to compare the colors to each other easily:

```
import UIKit

let myFirstColor = UIColor.red
let mySecondColor = UIColor.red
let myThirdColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
let iosWhite = UIColor.white
let myWhite = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

myFirstColor == mySecondColor //True
myFirstColor == myThirdColor //True
iosWhite == myWhite // True
```

From comments, there edge cases. I think these are all `gray`s `black`, `white` and `clear`. To compensate, you can create your own `grays` and compare to it:

```
let myOtherWhite = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

which is **not equal** to `UIColor.white`

That said, it is easy to find the edge cases on playground: 
[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for `UIColor.white` and `UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)`

Comment: Try it in playground. White has only w:1.0 and a:1.0

Comment: Exactly, they are created differently, that's why it's an appropriate edge case

Comment: The other one is better! I hope that mine can help to better understand, so, I  will leave it here. Cheers!

Comment: @AppzYourLife, why did you delete your answer? It looked promising... and thanks for the edit. It perfectly focused my question.

Comment: I have actually thought of a simpler way -- not foolproof bur good enough for my purposes: Take the values of r, g, b, a and add them together. Limit to five or six decimal places. I have gotten great results.